# Heap C data storage

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, heap

I am writing a heap data structure in C. Theres one thing that I can't decide on. I am implementing it as an array. The way it works, is that function "insert" takes a pointer to some data and copies all bytes of that data, pointed to, into the array, is that a good approach? Or should I just store the pointer itself, the function was called with?

Comment: If the pointer points to something already on the heap, you should just store the pointer.

Comment: It is supposed to be generic, so I have no control over where the data was allocated.

Comment: Then it depends on the semantics of the function, if you can guarantee that the caller will give ownership to the function.

Comment: what's the purpose of your data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to consider that the memory pointed to will probably be changed or become invalid, for example when it's a variable on the stack. So in most cases, it would not be a good idea to just store the pointer.
If you *must* have a function insert() there is no way around copying the memory - although this is slow. Best is to use memcpy(), because this is still the fastest function.

Heaps are usually designed a bit differently: You have a function malloc(int size) that you call to *retrieve* a pointer to a memory area of desired size. There you can store whatever you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

If the inserted object is allocated with malloc/calloc yes, you should store the pointer.Expecially with structs, copying the object may increase the overhead.